# Complexity of calculating independence number of a hypergraph

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Let $G$ be a "hypergraph", a collection of vertices $V=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ and a collection of "hyperedges" $E=\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_m\}$, where $e_i\subseteq V$ and unlike normal edges, an edge may contain more than two vertices.

An "independent set" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) is a collection of vertices, $U$, that does not fully contain any of the hyperedges:  $e_i\not\subseteq U$.  The "independence number" or "maximum independent set size" is the size of the largest independent set in the graph $G$.

I know that finding if there is an independent set of size $k\in\mathbb{N}$ in some normal graph $G$ is NP-Complete.  If I am not mistaken, this holds for hypergraphs as well.  However calculating the independence number is not proven to be NP.  Even approximating it is not proven in NP.

First, is there a more specific complexity class for calculating the independence number than NP-Hard?

Second, how much harder is it for a hypergraph?  Again, is there a complexity class more specific?

For related questions, a recent dissertation has been helpful to me: https://escholarship.org/uc/item/79t9b162.

Thanks!

Comment: it would be helpful to describe or ref the exact defn of hypergraph independent set (eg what pg in the dissertation etc)

Comment: I added definitions.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Are the $e_i \in E$ themselves sets (collections)? A polynomial-time reduction from HYPER-INDEPENDENT-SET to INDEPENDENT-SET seems trivial. I don't think a hyper graph is "stronger" than a regular graph: you can simulate a hyper graph with a regular graph. Looking at the reduction is where I'd start (to optimize max independent set on hyper graph). Any NP-complete problem is NP-hard by definition.

Comment: Yes, the $e_i$ are sets of vertices.  If you mean a bipartite graph representation of the hypergraph, wouldn't independent sets on such a graph be unrelated to the independent sets on the hypergraph?  I am aware that NP-complete is in NP-hard, I should have said "not proven to be in NP".  I'll edit.

Comment: sounds like you basically want _maximum independent set_ size? that is the typical term

Comment: On the bright side, I'm making headway; apparently Karp and Wigderson showed that finding maximal independent sets in graphs is in NC (Nick's Class, a parallel computing class) and it was an open question as of 2001 whether or not a maximal independent set in a hypergraph can be found in NC.  This does not directly say anything about the size of the maximum independent set, but now I have a reference to go from:  "Finding Large Independent Sets of Hypergraphs in Parallel" by Shachnai and Srinivasan.

Comment: Okay, I added that term to the question.  Thank you.

Comment: there seems to be recent/active research eg by [Saket](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.2915v1.pdf) but its more about approximability hardness results. when you ask for "more specific class" do you mean, is it known to be harder than NP-Hard? saket's are indeed "more specific results" but not nec in terms of a "more specific class"....

Comment: That's great, I think these collections of specific approximate results will be better than a huge computational class for the exact result.  If you would like to put that into an answer this could be closed, probably?

Comment: FWIW, if a bipartite graph can be used to represent hyper graphs, then I agree the reduction is not as trivial as simply converting the hyper graph $\langle H \rangle$ to a bipartite graph $\langle G \rangle$ and running some algo that finds max independent set on $\langle G \rangle$. There would be some more sophisticated gadgetry in the reduction if this route were to be taken. At any rate, if you need a production-level solution, then best of luck to you.

Comment: You're right of course, the way to look at the complexity of the independence number is probably going to be looking at graph to hypergraph, calculating some slightly different problem with some gadgets in the way.  However, without a specific complexity for calculating the independence number for graphs there isn't going to be anything to start with.  We might have to be satisfied with Saket's active research.

Comment: JM "good enough" is not always accepted around stackexchange & thx for your flexibility on that, wrote up more detail incl Sakets nice slide show summary/overview etc. by the way/fyi (see you are new around here) questions are generally not "closed", they are only put on "hold" if they are unacceptably stated, they stay "open" indefinitely, although any answers tend to materialize within a few days if ever...

Comment: "However calculating the independence number is not proven to be NP." Calculating any number is not in NP because NP is a class of decision problems: problems where the answer is either "yes" or "no".

Comment: @DavidRicherby: It is clear that the decision version is in NP.  Just give the set of vertices forming a large enough independent set.

Comment: @Louis The decision version "Is the independence number at least $k$" is clearly in NP, yes. The decision problem "Is the independence number exactly $k$" is not AFAIK known to be in NP (you can show me an independent set of size $k$ but how do you convince me there aren't any bigger ones?) And, in any case, the question is specifically about the function problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did not find a proof of complexity class harder than "NP hard" for this problem (ie the presumably more complex hypergraph version of the problem does not seem to have been proven harder than the graph version) however did find the following. Saket has recent research in the area. results in complexity theory in active areas of research tend to be highly specialized and in the form "for limited hypergraph types [x], the following improved complexity bound [y] is shown." (ie more as approximability results, & more specialized than what you request but it can be mined for nearest desirable results/refs.)

basically hypergraphs while an old mathematical concept are a more recent area of complexity theory research and there is a large active/ongoing research program of determining complexity of operations around them and how those complexities relate to corresponding graph operation complexities, and translating theorems and knowledge about graphs into their hypergraph analogs.

- [Hardness of Finding Independent Sets in 2-Colorable Hypergraphs and of Satisﬁable CSPs](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.2915v1.pdf) Saket (Dec 2013)

  > This work revisits the PCP Veriﬁers used in the works of H˚astad [H˚as01], Guruswami et al. [GHS02],
  > Holmerin [Hol02] and Guruswami [Gur00] for satisﬁable MAX-E3-SAT and MAX-Ek-SET-SPLITTING,
  > and independent set in 2-colorable 4-uniform hypergraphs. We provide simpler and more efficient PCP
  > Veriﬁers to prove ... improved hardness results ...
- [Hardness of Maximum Independent Set in Structured Hypergraphs](http://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/555/saketslides.pdf) Saket powerpoint slides overview